# Forcing package to attach without masking warning

Tags: r, package, r-s3

Is there a way to specify that a library should not throw warnings regarding name clashes and masked objects whenever it is attached? I imagine a solution would involve editing the description or one of the special functions such as `.onAttach` but I can't find anything solving this issue.

I ask becuase the warnings are unneeded. I have defined my own `S3` class and the masked function is still called by the default method of the masking function:

```
median <- function(x, ...) UseMethod("median")

median.default <- stats::median.default
```

In the event that a user is using median on a typical R data structure such as a vector, the `median` method in my package will call the masked function automatically, so there is no real need for the user to be aware of the masking.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if your question is that you don't want the user to see the warnings, or that you don't want the warnings to occur.

If the former, you might be able to use `shhh` in the `tfse` library around your library call. Or, if it's just for yourself, you could set the `warn.conflicts = FALSE` argument when calling the library.

If the latter, it would be clearly more elegant to rewrite the offending method so it doesn't conflict in the namespace.